# how to plot `max(0,x)` function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried the following two ways. It seems to me they all take `x` as a vector instead of a single point. Is there a way to correctly plot this function?

```
eq = function(x){max(x,0)}
curve(eq, from=1, to=50, , xlab="x", ylab="y")
# It produces the following error:
#Error in curve(eq, from = 1, to = 50, , xlab = "x", ylab = "y") : 
#  'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1,50)), aes(x=x)) + stat_function(fun=eq)
#It will draw a horizontal line at x=50
```

Comment: Change `max` to `pmax`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want parallel maxima, `pmax`.

```
eq = function(x){pmax(x,0)}

curve(eq, from=-50, to=50, , xlab="x", ylab="y")

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-50,50)), aes(x=x)) + stat_function(fun=eq)
```

[image]